# Are the Sign-Extend and Shift Left 2 units used for the CBZ instruction?

Tags: assembly, arm

What exactly is the purpose of the Sign-Extend and Shift left 2 units for instruction data path in ARM, and are they used in Compare and Branch on Zero instruction?

Comment: What block diagram are you looking at?  Are you talking about how the relative displacement (in units of 2-byte halfwords) encodes a byte offset to be added to PC?  ARM Thumb CBZ can only branch forwards, not backwards, so I'd expect it to zero-extend its immediate.  ([*The branch destination must be within 4 to 130 bytes after the instruction and in the same execution state.*](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289867296.htm))

Comment: If you're talking about AArch64 CBZ (which can branch backwards and does encode the signed offset shifted by 2), tag your question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly is the purpose of the ... Shift left 2 units ...

In classic ARM instruction set (this means: not "Thumb") instructions must be located at an address that is a multiple of 4.

If you would implement a branch instruction that can jump in a 256 byte range (just as an example), you would need 8 bits to store the jump destination in the branch instruction.

However, because the jump destination must always be a multiple of 4, the low 2 bits of these 8 bits would always be zero. You would waste two bits of memory per instruction.

For this reason, many CPU instruction sets (and one of them is ARM) do not store the low 2 bits in such a situation.

Instead of saying: "*The operand is shifted left by 2 bits*" you might also say: "*The bits in the instruction are bits 7..2 of the operand and bits 1 and 0 of the operand are defined to be zero*".

The `B` instruction in classic ARM instruction set has 19 of 21 bits stored in the instruction (and the low two bits are defined to be 0).

> What exactly is the purpose of the Sign-Extend ...

When using twos complement arithmetic, a number whose most significant bit is 1 can be interpreted differently depending if the number is "unsigned" or "signed". The 5-bit value `11010` can be interpreted as `unsigned` value `42` or as `signed` value `-6`.

As long as you are adding two numbers with the same number of bits, it does not matter if the number is "unsigned" or "signed" - the result would be the same in both cases.

However, int the example above, you are adding an 5-bit operand (`11010`) to the (maybe) 32-bit program counter.

(In the classic ARM instruction set, an 21-bit number is added to the 32-bit PC register.)

You must know if `11010` means `-6` or `42`, so you can either subtract `6` from the program counter or add `42`.

If you add two numbers that have a different number of bits, you need to know this information about the number that has less bits!

"Sign-extend" simply means that the number must be treated as "signed" number (so `11010` is `-6) while "zero-extend" means that it must be treated as "unsigned" number (so` 11010`is`42`).

"Sign-extending" makes sense because it allows adding negative numbers to the PC - which means that jumping backwards is possible.

Using "zero-extending" jumping backwards would not be possible.

> ... are they used in Compare and Branch on Zero instruction?

On 32-bit ARM CPUs, `CBZ` is only available in "Thumb" mode. In this mode, the instructions can be located at even addresses (this means: divisible by 2). For this reason, the operands are shifted by 1 bit, not by 2 bits.

Furthermore, the `CBZ` instruction can only jump forward in "Thumb" mode (because Zero-Extension is used). This makes sense if the `CBZ` instruction is intended to be used at the start of an `if()` instruction, so the instruction jumps to the `else` part.

Using Zero-Extension, it is possible to jump to an `else` part that is further away (compared to Sign-Extension), so the instruction can still be used if the `if()` part is longer.

However, jumping backwards (e.g. at the end of a `do...while();` loop) is not possible.

In 64-bit ARM CPUs (AArch64), `CBZ` uses sign-extension and shifting by 2 bits.

Comment: I suspect Thumb CBZ is partly designed for `for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++)` loops that might need to run zero iterations, to skip over a loop body that used `subs` / `bne` at the bottom.  (asm do{}while())